# How to manually prevent sql injection by escaping strings inserted into MySQL statements

Tags: mysql

I need to generate MySQL INSERT and UPDATE statements from a text list of string parameters. It's basically a matter of inserting strings into placeholders, like so:

Input file

```
apple
banana
orange
```

Script (imagine a simple Ruby or Python program or Bash script) generates output:

```
INSERT INTO fruits (name) values ('apple');
INSERT INTO fruits (name) values ('banana');
INSERT INTO fruits (name) values ('orange');
```

This output will then be saved to a file which will later be piped into STDIN of the `mysql` command to update a database, much like one uses output from `mysqldump`.

But I would like to add some code to prevent either accidental or intentional SQL injection. I assume that this begins with prepending a backslash before any single quote character or backslash character in the input file entries. Is there anything else that needs to be done? I used this webpage as reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Comment: How are you generating these statements? In some languages, a proper MySQL escaping function is already available.

Comment: @delnan I am aware of that, but for certain reasons I would like to know whether the above approach is possible and safe.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first do some basic reading on the topic of 'SQL Injection' and how to prevent it. Hint: you need to find how to use a placeholder argument; this depends on the Database and Database library being used. It may be as simple as putting a ? where you need to put an argument (in the SQL you prepare), and then providing a suitable list of values for the ?s (when you execute the query).

Comment: I've used libraries with placeholder arguments plenty of times. I wanted to know about how to generate SQL statements as mysqldump would.